# Method if P Id is true

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to trigger an window open event such as "window.open" whenever the  within the body of the document, the elements "P id" becomes true.

So when, within the body of the page, this ID happens to load:

```
<p id=newPlayListText>
"There is a new playlist that was sent to you, check it out here."
```

I can triggered the event of "window.open".

This is what i have and after inspecting it, its not flagging anything to debug and nothing happens...

```
//@test: check to see if the new playlist banner text pops up during ep. 
window.onload = function () {
if(element.id = "nextPlaylistText") {
window.open("http://www.w3schools.com");
}
```

Please help

Comment: look at this https://jsfiddle.net/cLs9hbxv/, this has no sense though

Comment: does this: _the elements "P id" becomes true._ actually mean that whenever the element with ID "newPlayListText" exists you should trigger the window popup? Besides, the "equals" condition is ==, not = ( = actually assigns the value of element.id to "nextPlaylistText") and element has to be defined first, else it will be the property id of undefined.

Answer (score 2):

The `window.onload` hook is called when the page loads, but `element` is never defined. You'll need to *assign* the variable to `element` before using it:

`var element = document.getElementById("newPlayListText");`

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your code. First as `Litty` correctly pointed out that `element` is never declared. Second you aren't comparing values within `if` block.

```
if(element.id = "nextPlaylistText") // required `===` or at-least `==`
```

P.S. some browsers may block this line `window.open`

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var p = document.getElementById('newPlayListText');
  if (!p) {
    alert('New playlist not found');
    return;
  }
  var popup = window.open("http://www.w3schools.com");
  if (!popup) {
    alert('Kindly un-block/disable pop-up blocker');
    return;
  }
};
```

```html
<p id="newPlayListText">There is a new playlist that was sent to you, check it out here.</p>
```

Comment: 1.) I have NO IDEA what you guys just said. At all. I am new to this.
2.) I added this to my previous code: /// var element = document.getElementById("newPlayListText"); /// and now i am getting an error code in debug saying: ERROR:EXPECTED A CONTIONAL EXPRESSION AND INSTEAD GOT AN ASSIGNMENT ///ERROR; UNMATCHED { ON LINE  <--- IN RELATION TO THE WINDOW.ON LOAD COMMAND

Comment: Please help me. I have KIK messenger or teamviewer to help as I am at witts end with this coding. out of ideass to why its not doing anything - KiK @apoc_ofwgkta

Comment: UPDATE: So i removed my Window.onload function complete but left in Litty var. then replaced my Windows.Onload function with Arvind's it see if it can minipulate the code if it happened to load as it should and it didnt - nothing happens at all with Arvinds coding. Just checking it with in the inspection debug and no syntex errors were noted, and nothing is even happening.

Comment: HELP PLZ I am not familar with all the verbage you guys are using

Comment: UPDATE: Left in Litty var and removed Arvind broken code. then i added this instead: if(element.id == 'newPlaylistText') {
    window.open("http://www.w3schools.com");
}  ////and it says ERROR: Syntex FAILED! CANNOT READ PROPRIETY 'ID' OF "NULL"

Comment: hOW CAN I JUST CHANGE THE URL WHEN <P ID = newPlayList> triggers in my browsers thats all i want to do

Comment: @BgnarTiimons, did the code worked  here `Run code snippet` ?